# What and why is the worst case for a set intersection O(n^2)?

Tags: python, set, time-complexity, intersection

On the [Python wiki page on timeComplexity](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity), the intersection between 2 sets is O(n^2).

I am having trouble understanding what exactly is the worst case here, and why is it O(n^2)

Comment: A bad hash function leading to everything getting hashed to same bucket. Then you are effectively doing a list operation and iterating on it.

Comment: The **worst case** for containment is O(n). Checking containment n times in that case is O(n^2). You don't generally expect the worst with sets though.

Comment: the worst case is probably when your hash set collides on every entry and membership testing degrades to linear time instead of constant time